# Spring Boot : An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I am trying to upgrade Spring dependency jars without upgrading the Spring Boot version in my project to fix some of CVE's reported.

So i am trying to upgrade the Spring dependencies to v5.3.24 . While the build seems to be fine, when i run the application, Spring Boot fails with below error.

I know i could only adjust Spring dependencie's version, but not spring boot. Appreciate any help to fix this.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:377)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.resourceHandlerMapping(Lorg/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper;Lorg/springframework/util/PathMatcher;Lorg/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManager;Lorg/springframework/format/support/FormattingConversionService;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceUrlProvider;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping;

The method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/fazshaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.24/33d2187c2bf1cb2c222bd1cc18b618736babcf3d/spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/fazshaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.24/33d2187c2bf1cb2c222bd1cc18b618736babcf3d/spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
```

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.13.RELEASE'
        junitVersion = "5.3.1"
        axonVersion='4.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
        classpath "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:$owaspVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: "org.owasp.dependencycheck"

apply from: "${rootDir}/build-support/packaging.gradle"
apply from: "${rootDir}/contracts/build.gradle"

group = 'com.testproj.relateditems'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name "testprojdoc-public"
        url "https://artifacthub-phx.oci.mytesthostcorp.com/testprojdoc-public"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile ('org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.1.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.axonframework', module: 'axon-server-connector'
    }

    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'shared-secrets-implementation', version: '2.0.404'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.5.0'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.13.RELEASE')
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.27'
    compile group: 'com.testproj.linkingservice', name: 'dtos', version: '0.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.2.13.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda', version: '2.9.9'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'secrets-management-vault-spring', version:'1.5.133'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'secrets-management-simple', version: '1.5.133'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'secrets-management-tls-common', version: '1.5.133'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'spring-pcp-monitoring', version: '0.3.3'
    compile group: 'net.bull.javamelody', name: 'javamelody-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.79.0'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'testapp-private-api-client-common', version: '0.884'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
    compile group: 'com.testproj', name: 'trusted-api-client', version: '1.1.57'
    compile group: 'org.jolokia', name: 'jolokia-core', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.jolokia', name: 'jolokia-spring', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jcl', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.3.24'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '5.3.24'


    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'

    compile group: 'com.mikesamuel', name: 'json-sanitizer', version: '1.2.2'
    compile group: 'com.thoughtworks.xstream', name: 'xstream', version: '1.4.19'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'
    compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-to-slf4j', version: '2.17.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-configuration2', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.4'
    compile group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '2.1.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-websocket', version: '9.0.55'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.55'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-annotations-api', version: '9.0.55'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-el', version: '9.0.55'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.17.1'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.7.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.7.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '5.7.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '5.7.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-crypto', version: '5.7.5'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '5.3.24'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.9'


    compile group: 'io.pcp.parfait', name: 'dxm', version: '0.5.1'
    compile group: 'io.pcp.parfait', name: 'parfait-core', version: '0.5.1'
    compile group: 'io.pcp.parfait', name: 'parfait-jdbc', version: '0.5.1'
    compile group: 'io.pcp.parfait', name: 'parfait-jmx', version: '0.5.1'
    compile group: 'io.pcp.parfait', name: 'parfait-pcp', version: '0.5.1'

    runtime('com.h2database:h2:2.0.206')
    runtime('com.testproj:testapp-contracts:+') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-core'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-1.2-api'
    }
    runtime group: 'com.testproj.linkingservice', name: 'linking-service-contract', version: '+', changing: true


    testCompile group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon-test', version: '4.1.1'
    implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.4.8'
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.0.206'
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.18.3')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    configurations {
        implementation {
            exclude group: 'com.google.j2objc', module:'j2objc-annotations'
            exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module:'jsr305'
            exclude group: 'com.google.errorprone', module:'error_prone_annotations'
            exclude group: 'org.checkerframework', module:'checker-qual'
            exclude group: 'org.codehaus.mojo', module:'animal-sniffer-annotations'
        }
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://build.engr.doc:9000/sonar"
    }
}

dependencyCheck {
    format = 'ALL'
    suppressionFile = "${rootDir}/owasp/suppressions.xml"
    failBuildOnCVSS = 0
}

task gruntStage(type: Exec) {
    println 'Task :gruntStage: Executing build.sh to build ui(webapp-src).'
    commandLine 'sh', './build.sh'

}

task buildui(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn gruntStage
    println 'Task :buildui: Copying static resources to public'
    from('webapp-src/stage/rsrc')
    into('src/main/resources/public')

}

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional = [
                    'srcVersion' : "${  buildInformation.tag}"
            ]
        }
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn buildui
```

Below is the dependency tree info for Spring-webmvc dependency.

```
gradle -q dependencies | grep spring-webmvc
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.2.12.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.12.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.3.24
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.12.RELEASE -> 5.3.24 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.24 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.3.24
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.24 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.3.24
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.12.RELEASE -> 5.3.24 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.24 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.2.12.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.12.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.3.24
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.24 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.11.RELEASE -> 5.3.24
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.12.RELEASE -> 5.3.24 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.24 (*)
```

Comment: You should let Spring Boot manage the dependency versions of Spring (and other libraries), not specify them yourself. For example, Spring Boot 2.2.13.RELEASE uses Spring 5.2.12.RELEASE. If you want to use a newer Spring version, you should also change your Spring Boot version. Likely your Spring Boot version tries to call a method from Spring 5.2 that no longer exists in Spring 5.3.

Comment: Correct your dependencies, some might be clashing or duplicate, hence the issue

Comment: You are using SPring Boot 2.2 which is old, you cannot upgrade a major version of SPring inside Spring Boot as that will lead to incompatible classes (as you noticed). Instead upgrade Spring Boot to 2.7.6 (which is the latest and includes the proper fixes). Quickly looking at your dependencies is that you define all the versions yourself, which kind of beats the purpose of the starter dependencies and lets you run the risk of including incompatible versions of modules.